# JSON parsing single qoutes in utf-8 error

Tags: php, utf-8, json

I've been going crazy over this one :

i HAD this code :

```
var names = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($names ); ?>');
```

Where `$names` is an array with utf-8 content in it.

Which worked fine but when the `$names` array contained `'` i started getting the `unexpected token/charachter` errors.

I tried all various kind of things such as :

```
var names = JSON.parse('<?php echo 
json_encode(str_replace("'","\'",$names),JSON_HEX_APOS  | JSON_HEX_QUOT ); ?>');
```

or

```
var names = JSON.parse('<?php
 echo json_encode($names,JSON_HEX_APOS  | JSON_HEX_QUOT ); ?>');
```

And non helped. i get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token` error.

```
var names = JSON.parse('{"1":{"136":{"0":"135 \u05dc\u05dc\u05d0 
 \u05d4\u05d2\u05d1\u05dc\u05d4"},"75":{"0":"\u05d1\u05d5\u05e0\u05d5\u05e1 75"},"199":
  {"0":"\u05d1\u05d5\u05e0\u05d5\u05e1 199"},"5":{"0":"card bonus 5"},"30":
  {"0":"\u05e1\u05dc\u05e7\u05d5\u05dd \u05d4\u05d5\u05d3\u05e2\u05d5\u05ea"},"40":{"0":"40
  \u05e2\u05e8\u05d1\u05d9\u05ea"}],"37":[{"0":"\u05d6\u05e8\u05d5 
 \u05d0\u05e0\u05d2\u05dc\u05d9\u05ea"}],"38":[{"0":"\u05d6\u05e8\u05d5 
 \u05e8\u05d5\u05e1\u05d9\u05ea"}],"39":
 [{"0":"\u05d6\u05e8\u05d5 \u05d8\u05d0\u05d9"}]}');
```

It's a very long string, i just cut in half so the syntax might appear incorrect but the general idea.

How can i get it to parse the array?

I'm using PHP 5.3 so i can't try `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` or `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` if it's related.

Answer (score 3):

Valid JSON is valid JavaScript; you can simply write:

```
var names = <?php echo json_encode($names ); ?>;
```

As for UTF-8 characters, here is a test:

```
<script>
alert(<?php echo json_encode("\xE2\x82\xAC"); ?>); // should alert €
</script>
```

Comment: But then when trying to use the var i get undefined as it's not defined as a valid object.

Comment: @eric.itzhak: i? where did i come from?

Comment: It's ok man i did it in a different way in the end... i can't delete the question because it's already been answered.. Thank you for your time!